# Saving current row is setting it to 0 index even though saved row number correct

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following to save the current row of a datagridview which is the right number index but its not shifting the row after the processing is done.

```
saveRow = dgStock.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

BindGrid();
if (saveRow != 0 && saveRow < dgStock.Rows.Count)
{
    dgStock.Rows[saveRow].Selected = true;
}
```

Was wondering if anybody has had any experience of this just wondering if it should be CurrentCell as per the way I am saving the index in the first place as it is setitng it to the first row here some reason after the re binding of the grid.

Comment: Did you change in some way the current order of the rows in the grid with that BindGrid()?

Comment: No the current order is the same  as before if I use FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex that gets the right row section but still does not highlight the row

Comment: how is the save called? Is it via another control? If it is via another control, it could be an issue where your grid is not in focus. Setting focus back to your datagridview before selecting it could resolve the issue.

Comment: @Riv that was actually the issue thanks